# How to use C# box-api to download or upload a file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, cloud, box-api

How to download a file and upload a file from box.com using C#. Is there any easy way to use the dlls to perform above tasks. I am using visual studio 2010. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read these [Box api](http://developers.box.net/w/page/12923951/ApiFunction_Upload%20and%20Download) and [.Net WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is older question but thought to share latest updates. As per the latest API from Box, [GitHub Box SDK V2](https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2#download-a-file), To Download a File we can use:

```
Stream stream = await client.FilesManager.DownloadStreamAsync(fileId);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Box's V2 API, we don't yet have a C# library ready.  You could write your own code to perform uploads and downloads (http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-download-a-file), or copy some code from our old library, that points to the V1 API: https://github.com/box/box-csharp-sdk .

Comment: Is it possible using Jquery ?